# Oracle get list of columns A,B,C,D only when group by A,B is more than a limit- need help on query

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle : get list of columns A,B,C,D from a table , only when count of group by A,B is more than a limit
Can someone help on the query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by a, b) as ab_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where ab_cnt > LIMIT;
```

This counts the number of rows for each a/b combination and returns the base rows where the count is over some limit.

Comment: Same table alias as table name can be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff gave you a perfectly fine solution, using analytic `COUNT(*)`.

If performance is important, you may want to try a different solution as well, using aggregation rather than analytic functions. The solution below requires reading the base table twice. Even with this overhead, experiments show that it may be (much) faster than solutions based on analytic functions; the best way to tell is by running both approaches on **your** actual data.

```
select *
from   (your table)
where  (a, b) in (
                   select a, b
                   from   (your table)
                   group  by a, b
                   having count(*) > LIMIT
                 )
;
```